# href adding extra information to the hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently generating an hyperlink so I can redirect people to correct webpages. The problem is that a correct hyperlink like:

www.reddit.com/r/magicTCG/comments/2ific1/sam_pardee_on_the_modern_jeskai_ascendancy_combo/'

in the href, redirects me to

exp/rdt/www.reddit.com/r/magicTCG/comments/2ific1/sam_pardee_on_the_modern_jeskai_ascendancy_combo/'

where exp/rdt is the path to the original index file on my ftp.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var hyperlink = "'www.reddit.com" + post.data.permalink + "'";

$("#searchesTable").append('<tr><td>' + post.data.title + '</td><td>' + post.data.ups + '</td><td>' + post.data.downs + '</td><td>' + formattedTime + '</td><td>' + post.data.subreddit + '</td><td>' + post.data.permalink + '</td><td><a href="' + hyperlink + '" ><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Visit!</button></a></td></tr>');
```

The problem, I think, comes from this bit of code:

```
<td><a href="' + hyperlink + '" ><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Visit!</button></a></td>
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Add http:// to your link

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the URL with the `http://` protocol code. Otherwise, the browser treats it as a relative link.

Answer (score 1):

You MUST add the protocol and you have too many quotes

```
var hyperlink = "http://www.reddit.com" + post.data.permalink;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for single quotes in

```
var hyperlink = "'www.reddit.com" + post.data.permalink + "'";
```

Also unless you specify the protocol the `href` would be relative to current path (With exception of the leading `/` - then it would be relative to the root path). Look up [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).

Here's minimal code to make it work:

```js
var post = {
  data: {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor',
    ups: 15,
    downs: 2,
    subreddit: 'whatever',
    permalink: '/r/magicTCG/comments/2ific1/sam_pardee_on_the_modern_jeskai_ascendancy_combo/'
  }
};

var formattedTime = 'Apr 12 2007';

var hyperlink = "http://www.reddit.com" + post.data.permalink;

$("#searchesTable").append('<tr><td>' + post.data.title + '</td><td>' + post.data.ups + '</td><td>' + post.data.downs + '</td><td>' + formattedTime + '</td><td>' + post.data.subreddit + '</td><td>' + post.data.permalink + '</td><td><a href="' + hyperlink + '" ><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Visit!</button></a></td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="searchesTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Just a quick question: apart from the snippet which basically copies OP's code, making your answer look bigger, what new revelations does this answer bring that was not already covered by the two other answers?

Comment: @mplungjan Out of other two answers only your answer is complete. It's not about size, but about quality. I provide explanation for observed behaviour instead of just throwing in the solution. Question to you is why do you pick on me when Scimonster's answer is not even different from your comment and is incomplete?

Comment: Besides that this question can be closed as off-topic anyway. Because it's pretty much a typo.

Comment: Scimonster was a few seconds after my comment and a few before my answer which indeed is more complete. I pick on you because your answer is 5 hours after and I get curious when I see large later answers with example code that does not imo add anything new but just looks more correct due to size. You deemed it off topic after writing such an elaborate answer? Weirder and weirder - never mind....